# I need a explaining for this short script

Tags: javascript, function, recursion

I have this code :

```
    function list(target, letters, lvls) {
    var index = 0;
    (function iter(s, lvl) {
        if(lvl++ == lvls)
            return target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                ++index + ' - ' + s + '\n'
            ));
        for(var i=0; i<letters.length; ++i)
            iter(s + letters[i], lvl);
    })('', 0);
  }
  list(document.getElementById('output'), 'abc', 3);
```

But I don't know this type of function syntax.
Can some one explain to me the function behavior and what this code exactly do step by step.
And thanks in advance

Comment: that is defining a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) and then executing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be iterating through the string 'abc' and creating as many X letter strings as possible with the combination of all the characters in the string.

So the call is `list([element ID to output strings], [string of all possible letters], [size of strings to generate])`

So the following example -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function list(target, letters, lvls) {
    var index = 0;
    (function iter(s, lvl) {
        if(lvl++ == lvls)
            return target.appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                ++index + ' - ' + s + '\n'
            ));
        for(var i=0; i<letters.length; ++i)
            iter(s + letters[i], lvl);
    })('', 0);
}
list(document.getElementById('output'), 'ab', 2);
</script>

<div id="output"></div>
```

will output all possible two letter strings (defined by param 3), using the characters from the input string (param 2) and will result in -

`1 - aa 2 - ab 3 - ba 4 - bb`

**Explanation**

Inside the method there is a second called `iter` with the arguments `s` and `lvls`. On 
first run, the arguments parsed to the `iter` method are blank and 0. It hits the for 
loop which runs until all of the letters in the string `letters` have been used up, 
each time recursively calling the iter method. Each time it adds the current letter in 
the iteration `s`, along with the next letter in the string `letters[i]`. Every time it 
recursively calls itself it builds up the string until the number of specified levels have 
been reached for that particular string and then returns the result, along with the `index` 
value. This is just a numeric value to represent the string count.

Comment: yes i know what's the main goal of this code : but i want to understand step by step how this script loop and the variables scoop to achieve those results !

Comment: @HCJPS I have updated my answer to include an explanation. I hope this makes sense to you. It is essentially leveraging a recursive strategy to loop through the string many times to produce the desired result.